# POST data not sent properly after preventDefault() - new Google's invisible reCAPTCHA related

Tags: javascript, php, post, recaptcha

**UPDATE 2**

Looks like I am having trouble accessing document elements (including form) from within the callback (onSubmit function) registered with invisible reCAPTCHA. Updated code below.

In browser console, I get the error message below when JS reaches "document.getElementById("info_form").submit()" call in JS:

*10:26:47.556 TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function 1* selector.php:13:9

The image CAPTCHA when it comes up is solved correctly and alert dialog displays it correctly. But, I can't submit form explicitly within callback to my backend. Please note that as per Google instructions in link below in message, I need to call preventDefault() as specified below. If I delete it, the reCAPTCHA flow is interrupted.

**UPDATE**

So, it looks like the "event.preventDefault();" is the key line here. If I have it, the reCAPTCHA (i.e. the image selection grid) gets displayed and I can interact with the widget. However, the POST parameters don't get sent. If I comment out the preventDefault(), the POST goes through correctly - BUT the reCAPTCHA flow does not start. This means, that while the other POST params get sent, the important reCAPTCHA data does not get sent since that flow is not executed at all.

So, how do I go about this? Looks like I need to call "preventDefault" before "grecaptcha.execute()" to enable reCAPTCHA flow (as Google also shows in their snippet). But doing so, messes up the POST data somehow. I am also explicitly calling "document.getElementById("info_form").submit()", but not helping. Any ideas would be great. Thx!

**Also, Google's invisible reCAPTCHA is a relatively new construct and still in beta.** Could be some core issues re: that. What we are all regularly used to is their regular reCAPTCHA where we see the "I am not a robot" checkbox. Invisible reCAPTCHA does not have that first line UI widget - and only steps you up to image CAPTCHA if nedeeded.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I need your help in figuring out why my 1) button onclick = validate function and 2) my form POST cannot co-exist.

Specifically, if I comment out the "document.getElementById('submit').onclick = validate" below, my form POST goes through successfully. However, if I register the validate function, the form POST does not work. Google tells me (Google link provided below) that if I want to validate input before performing invisible reCAPTCHA, I need to call "grecaptcha.execute();" during button onclick event.

**So, my general question is**, after executing (or within) the button onclick = validate function, how I can make sure that the info_form is submitted normally via POST so I can see it in my backend PHP? Not necessarily that the POST "itself" isn't working - but the parameters that would get submitted via POST may be getting messed up somehow - just a thought.

Source code and further code specific comments below. Also, please note that I already have the other two forms of reCAPTCHA binding working in the Google link. The "grecaptcha.execute()" variant is the only one I am having trouble with.

```
<?php
   include 'msg_recaptcha.php'; // use the debugMessage output
?>

<html>
<head>

<script>

function onSubmit(callbackInput) 
{
    var message = "g-recaptcha-response token successfully received.\n";
    message += "Token = ";
    message +=  callbackInput;
    alert(message);

    document.getElementById("info_form").submit();    
}

function validate(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (!document.getElementById('firstname').value) {
     alert("Please enter name");
   } else {
      grecaptcha.execute();
   }
}
</script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
 <form id='info_form' action="invisible_recaptcha_form.php" method="post">
 First name: <input id="firstname" name="firstname">
 Second name: <input id="secondname" name="secondname">

 <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
      data-sitekey="<Site key (public) from Google>"
      data-callback="onSubmit"
      data-size="invisible">
 </div>
 <button id='submit'>submit</button>
```

If I comment out the "onclick = validate" line below, my server PHP will receive the form details via POST - including first name. However, I can't comment it out in final solution, since I need to run the recaptcha "execute" function in validate() function as per Google's instructions  https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible. The problem with Google's instructions is that, they don't show how to do the POST along with their grecaptcha.execute() requirements - and I would need both to ensure the payload from the reCAPTCHA operation gets sent in the POST to my backend, so that my backend can talk to Google server's to validate the reCAPTCHA payload.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = validate;
</script>

<div id="debugmessage"><?=$debugMessage?> </div>
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your **onSubmit** JS function to execute form submit after recaptcha validation.

```
function onSubmit(token) {
   alert('thanks ' + document.getElementById('firstname').value);
   document.getElementById("info_form").submit();
}
```

**UPDATE**

When you call `event.preventDefault()` at your onsubmit eventHandler, you say to the browser to not execute form submit by default and that YOU will do it when you need.

Comment: Thx Pedro. Sadly, just adding that line is not working for me. I tried it earlier as well. It's so frustrating! :(

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are accepting parameter into validate function

```
function validate(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (!document.getElementById('firstname').value) {
 alert("Please enter name");
   } else {
  grecaptcha.execute();
   }
```

but you are not passing any parameter to validate

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = validate
```

that is the reason its giving you error.

modify your validate function to take no argument. I'm thinking why you need to take argument into validate function when you are not using it anywhere?

Comment: Thx. Fair point. But, that didn't fix the issue either. I deleted the "event" parameter - but still no good :(.

Comment: call your function as Validate()

Comment: Tried renaming, in case there is "some" naming conflict. No difference even after renaming. Provided more info in the "Update" section.

Comment: how could you call preventDefault when you deleted event parameter, you need not to have preventDefault, also your other funtion has nothing to do with preventDefaul()

Comment: When calling preventDefault, the event param needs to be there - obviously, that param needs to be re-added to call the preventDefault function. Please see last code snippet at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible.